# How to omit NullPointerException in this test case of Spring boot web app method?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit

I do have a problem with redirect attribute in my spring web app method. Here's the method:

```
@RequestMapping("/employee")
public String saveEmployee(@ModelAttribute EmployeeCommand commandObject){

    EmployeeCommand savedCommand = employeeService.saveEmployeeCommand(commandObject);

    return "redirect:/employee/" + savedCommand.getId();
}
```

I have written a test:

```
@Test
public void saveEmployee() throws Exception {

    //given
    EmployeeCommand employeeCommand = new EmployeeCommand();
    employeeCommand.setId(2L);

    //when
    when(employeeService.saveEmployeeCommand(employeeCommand)).thenReturn(employeeCommand);

    //then
    mockMvc.perform(post("/employee"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
            .andExpect(redirectedUrl("redirect:/employee/2"));

    verify(employeeService, times(1)).saveEmployeeCommand(employeeCommand);
}
```

I keep getting a `NullPointerException` related to that line:

```
return "redirect:/employee/" + savedCommand.getId();
```

It seems that `savedCommand` is null. Any tips?

Comment: are you not getting any errors? Anything while saving?

Comment: No. Should I get any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
mockMvc.perform(post("/employee")).flashAttr("commandObject", employeeCommand));
```

Right now you are only perfmorming post request without passing commandObject and therefore this mock:

```
when(employeeService.saveEmployeeCommand(employeeCommand)).thenReturn(employeeCommand);
```

Does not trigger

Comment: I'll try that. Would that also work if I changed `employeeCommand` to `any()`?

Comment: It also works with `any()` but this will also trigger when passing `null` - it is usually better to use `any(EmployeeCommand.class)` to atleast make sure that the parameter type is correct